# Checking if result of st_difference is empty

Tags: postgis, polygon, line, st-difference, st-touches

I am trying to select lines that completely touch a polygon (not at just a single point).

I would assume it would be a simple case of [st_isempty](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsEmpty.html)([st_difference](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html)(geom_a,geom_b)).

However, this is not the case as you can see in the following picture.

[image]

I would like to only have the highlight yellow lines returned. What am I doing wrong?

(I could solve it with a string comparison, but I would like to avoid the extra "st_astext" invocation).

The query:

```
SELECT a.geometry, 
       a.id as a_id, 
       b.FID as b_id,
       st_astext(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry),1)) as st_difference,
       st_isempty(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry),1)) as st_isempty
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON st_touches(a.geometry,b.geometry)
```

Comment: What if you apply [`ST_NumPoints()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumPoints.html) with [`CASE`-Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp), e.g. `CASE WHEN ST_NumPoints(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry),1)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Can it suit your solution?

Comment: Alternatively you may try [`ST_IsValid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html), i.e. `ST_IsValid(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry),1))`

Comment: @Taras, ST_IsValid indeed provides the correct results. Do you mind posting your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it? And do you know why st_isempty doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without seeing the data.  Can you post a polygon and two lines with different results?

Comment: @dr_jts I don't think data is the issue. st_difference returns empty geometry on the proper rows (as per the documentation), but st_isempty doesn't report "true" as it should (as per the documentation)

Comment: @pkExec the syntax `LINESTRING()` is not the correct representation for an empty linestring - in fact it's not valid WKT syntax.  Given that it's hard to say what is actually being provided as input to ST_IsEmpty.  `select st_isempty('LINESTRING EMPTY');` certainly works correctly in PostGIS.

Comment: I would be glad seeing your data input (i.e. polygons and lines) as a graphic. I do not really understand this *lines completely touch a polygon*.

Comment: I highly recommend that you use a different binary predicate instead of doing geometric operations, check out https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CoveredBy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue I can suggest trying another approach with using the [`ST_IsValid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) that is a boolean and works as `T(1)/F(0)`. So, you query will look as

```sql
SELECT a.geometry, 
       a.id as a_id, 
       b.FID as b_id,
       st_astext(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry), 1)) as st_difference,
       ST_IsValid(ST_GeometryN(st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry), 1)) as st_isvalid
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON st_touches(a.geometry, b.geometry)
```

I can be wrong but your issue has probably something to do with a warning described in [`ST_IsEmpty()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsEmpty.html)

> Changed: 2.0.0 In prior versions of PostGIS
> ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(EMPTY)') was allowed. This is now
> illegal in PostGIS 2.0.0 to better conform with SQL/MM standards